# How can I improve the efficiency of QA?

Tags: team-management, quality-management

One of my colleagues is in charge of QA (acceptance testing), and I keep on having to double check his work, and when I do, I find bugs - it is becoming tedious.

Short of double checking his work, how can I improve the process so that it is more efficiently done?

Comment: Do you have documented acceptance criteria he is missing? Or are you just better at randomly testing and finding defects? If you have documented criteria, has he given any reason why he missed them?

Comment: Have a documented acceptance criteria, sometimes the QA guy does not follow it strictly. I find out after I double check his work. He hasn't given any good reason, except, 'oh ok'

Comment: You should use test evidence attached to test plan.
With screenshots, screencasts, server logs, sql query results, xmls - some artifacts that are rock solid evidence that test is passed.

Comment: This questions looks more like a rant against specific low-performing person.

Answer (score 6):

Let's divide QA(Quality Assurance) from QC(Quality control), check the [difference](http://www.diffen.com/difference/Quality_Assurance_vs_Quality_Control).

Short term solution for manual QC would be to create test plans, acceptance criteria's, force your QC to add test evidence(Screenshots, screencasts, logs, SQL query results), which prove that all ok, you should also plan the number of bugs based on previous development history. For instance, on one of my projects, used only manual QC, there was 0.8-1.2 bug for each 10 hours of development. That means that for 40h feature there must be from 3.2 to 4.8 defects. So I shall plan to find at least to find at least 5 of them.

General advice would be to switch from QC to QA. On all stages of the project. [Example](http://codemanship.co.uk/parlezuml/tutorials/agile_qa/Example_Agile_Quality_Assurance_Strategy.pdf).

Answer (score 0):

Clearly document the *finds* in emails to your colleague, and CC this colleague's direct boss (and maybe the one above them).

After 3 such emails it's appropriate to ask the boss to request your colleague to either shape up or ship out.

(Most times, after one such email+CC your colleague will make sure to clean up their act.)